# Prove about eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Prove that if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are different eigenvalues of $f$ and $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors asociated with them respectively, then $v + w$ is not an eigenvector of $f$.

What could be the statement to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are linearly independent.